# laravel connection refused with mysql database in cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cpanel, host

I have deployed new laravel 8 application in cpanel.I'm having trouble connecting to the mysql database to laravel application deployed in capnel.
In my local environment database connection works fine . However on my remote server it does not work.

my .env looks like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=project_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=dev
```

when DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 it shows

> error sqlstate[2002] connection refused(select * from)

when DB_HOST=localhost it shows

> error sqlstate[2002] no such file or directory(select * from)

can you guys spot my error
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL via command-line on the server?

Answer (score 0):

> You can retrieve hostname from the control panel and add changes to your file else you'll get permission denied.

> Not all shared hosting provide MySQL on the same localhost as the HTTP
> server. You should check your cpanel for the address of the MySQL
> server:

[you can get more detail from here](https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/what-is-mysql-hostname-24)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30745320)